# React invoking function calling setState passed in props of a stateless component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on filter component being made with React.JS.
A few of those filtering components are embedded in a panel (`div`). The wrapping parts of the panel look like the below:

```
        Initiative <a onClick={() => {this.setState({ showInitiatives: true })}} className="milestone-list-link" href="#initiative">
          {this.state.selectedInitiative}
          <InitiativeSelector
            initiatives={initiatives || {}}
            show={this.state.showInitiatives}
            selector={
              () => {
                console.log('called selector state:', this.state)
                this.setState({ showInitiatives: false })
              }
            }
          />
          <FilterIcon />
        </a>
```

My `<InitiativeSelector />` looks like the below:

```
const InitiativeSelector = ({initiatives, show, selector}) => {
  return (show) ? (
    <div className="list-filter">
      <div>
        <input placeholder="Search..." />
      </div>
      <ul>
        {
          Object.values(initiatives).map((initiative, i) => <li onClick={() => {selector()}} key={i}>{initiative.name}</li> )
        }  
      </ul>
    </div>
  ) : null
}
```

When I run this, my `selector` does get called. Hence, I see state printed to the console. However, `this.setState({ showInitiatives: false })` does not seem to do anything. My modal does not hide, and the second (etc) time I click on the `<li>`, `showInitiatives` still set to `true`.

Comment: Solution for the question???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because click event bubbles up the DOM tree combined with async nature of `setState`

First `li.onClick` fires calling `selector` which calls `setState({ showInitiatives: false})`

Then `a.onClick` fires calling `setState({ showInitiatives: true })`. You could check it is true say by adding log statement to it.

Now you have 2 pending updates

```
{ showInitiatives: false}
{ showInitiatives: true}
```

which when merged is noop.

You need to either stop event propagation inside `li.onClick` by calling `e.stopPropagation()` or rethink what `a.onClick` handler is doing.

Comment: @AshishChoudhary The last sentence.